# Elements not displaying until hovered over

Tags: jquery, opencart

I'm working on a site for a client and am experiencing some sort of bug in Chrome.

http://timkeaydesign.com/nnc/desktops

If you switch to "grid" view, then refresh the page, you'll see how the page should display. If you switch to "list" view then back to "grid" view, most of the "add to basket" buttons disappear... until you start hovering around on the others, then they gradually start re-appearing!?

This bug only appears to be present in Chrome. I've tested this in Firefox, Safari and IE8 and it seems fine in those browsers.

I've updated jQuery and fixed a few javascript errors, but this hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your JavaScript code( specifically the display('') function). The CSS might be right depending on how your code is structured.

Comment: +1, even better, provide the code on a live example on jsfiddle.com . Isolate the issue is always the key...

Comment: It says that it's too long to paste in here. If you view the page source from the original linked page, the function can be found starting at line 487, ending at 575. Thanks. It's the original code that came with the default OpenCart installation theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the Position:Absolutes and modify the way your HTML structure is.

CSS:

```
       .product-grid .cart {
            padding: 10px;
            display:block;
        }

       .product-grid .wishlist, .product-grid .compare {
            bottom: 70px;
            z-index: 999;
        }
```

JS (move cart to the bottom):

```
   html += '<div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
   html += '<div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';
   html += '<div class="cart">' + $(element).find('.cart').html() + '</div>';
```

Comment: @timkeay No problem, anytime :P